# i have the ts.1005 error and i want create method inside method . this can possible?

Tags: javascript

I want to send data to the controller inside the method and I have this error ts.1005

```
if (edit === true) {
  updateTodo(update) {
    todoListItemSpan.contentEditable = true;
    todoListItemSpan.addEventListener("keyup", () => {
      todoTextUpdate = todoListItemSpan.textContent;
      update(id, todoTextUpdate);
    });
  }

}
```

Comment: You're missing the keyword `function` at the beginning of the function definition. i.e. `function updateTodo(update) { ... }`

Comment: its the method inside the class

Comment: You can only define methods like that at the top-level of the class definition, not inside an `if` statement. This is defining an ordinary function, not a method.